# NSFetchedResultsController section grouping by relation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have a Core Data entity which I am trying to display in a table view using an NSFetchedResultsController.  The relevant model attributes looks something like this:

**Post**

- parentPost (OtM relation)
- childPosts (inverse of parentPost)
- rootParent (OtM relation, points to the top of the tree)
- allChildren (inverse of rootParent, shows the flattened children of a root object)

The relations form a tree with the root Post being the one where parentPost = nil.  The way I want this to display is that every root post is the first item in a section and then the rest of the rows are a flattened list of the children of the root.

This is easy enough to arrange manually by doing a fetch request like this:

```
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Post.entityName())
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentPost = NULL")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortOrder.sortDescriptors
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["allChildren"]
```

Then I can build the section array from each of the results doing something like this:

```
    let sectionPost = self.fetchedResultsController!.fetchedObjects![section] as! Post
    var sectionArray = NSMutableArray(object: sectionPost)
    var filteredSet = sectionPost.allChildren.filteredOrderedSetUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "approved != FALSE AND postDeleted != TRUE AND spam != TRUE"))
    sectionArray.addObjectsFromArray(filteredSet.array)
```

The question is: is there a way to do this all within the FRC?  Maintaining a separate datasource from the FRC is complicated and I'd rather find a way to do this with a single fetch request but I don't see a great way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no the grouping must happen on a key on the entity. so use a transient property or a fetched property to get the relation and make it a key

in your case.. e.g. make all POST objects have a key 'postToGroupBy' or 'postNameToGroupBy or whatever so the post and all its children are in the same group

Comment: How does adding a fetched property solve the issue?  The only way to section out FRC results is the sectionNameKeyPath property and I'm not visualizing how what you are saying is going to work.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: BTW, I'm using Mogenerator to generate class files so relations are already keys on the Post object.  But I still don't see how I can make them into sections using these properties.

Comment: Ahhh...I get what you are saying now.  Although low tech this solution should solve the problem, thanks!